# InvalidIndexError: You can only assign a scalar value not a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Tags: time-series, predict, sarimax

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfXGi.png)

## Hello

I am trying to press the spx with a sarimas model, however i have not been able to solve this error, i would be grateful if you could give me guidance.

InvalidIndexError: You can only assign a scalar value not a <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

[Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1HNxffJ2jWR3IOeR-5ho318jOZJvbaSut?usp=sharing)

I need this code segment to cover the process of making time series predictions, handling the transformations applied to the data, and managing the in-sample and out-of-sample predictions along with their confidence intervals.